Jingle bells, Christmas sells!
What popular present, and from where, do you think I want this Christmas?
Things I want
Biography of Muammar Gaddafi
Doll from Mattel
False teeth
Lego Technic UFO
Pan flute
Playmobil bulldozer
Portrait of Charles I
Santa’s sleigh
Shampoo
Tea set
The Wailers’ 1973 album Burnin’
Toy dog house
Places of origin
Edmonton
Evendale, Ohio
New Delhi
Nuremberg
Oxford
Reed City, Michigan
Trondheim
Urbandale, Iowa
Venice
Verona
Wollongong
Xanthi
In order
[1] from –
– from [6]
[3] from –
[4] from –
[5] from –
[2] from –
[11] from –
– from [5]
– from [6]
[6] from –
– from [1]
– from [6]

I think that for Christmas, you want...

 ...a Barbie doll. Whatever it is, it is PLASTIC from CHINA.

The thought that finally led me to solve this puzzle was the realisation that...

 ...there are some very obscure cities include on this list - particularly the three accompanied by a state name: Evendale, Reed City, and Urbandale. And all of these words begin with letters that end spelled-out numbers: sEVEN/elEVEN, thREE, and foUR... So was it possible to pair the gifts and the cities in order to spell out numbers?

It was!

 [P]laymobil bulldoZER, Oxford
 ShampoO, NEw De[l]hi
 Te[a] seT, WOllongong
 Fal[s]e teeTH, REEd City, Michigan
 Lego [T]echnic UFO, URbandale, Iowa
 B[i]ography of Muammar GaddaFI, VErona
 Portrait of [C]harleS I, Xanthi

 Toy dog houSE, VENi[c]e
 Santa’s slEIGH, Trond[h]eim
 The Wa[i]lers’ 1973 album BurNIN’, Edmonton
 Pan fluTE, [N]uremberg
 Doll from MattEL, EVENd[a]le, Ohio

 Here, you can clearly see the numbers from ZERO to ELEVEN spelled out in order between the two paired halves. If we order them like this (with the space) to match the extraction template given at the end of the puzzle, and then extract the letter in the specified numbered position of the relevant half (e.g. "[1] from –" means the 1st letter from the gift name, and "– from [6]" means the 6th letter from the location name), we extract the phrase ""PLASTIC from CHINA.

The final answer doesn't need extracting in the same way as the puzzle method so far (at least I can't spot anything that way). Instead...

 ...I have assumed that the list of gifts has been given in order of increasing preference, and that you really want the last item on your list more than the others - "Doll from Mattel". This coupled with "Plastic from China" - plus a 2023 movie and recent resurgence - leads me to suggest this is likely to be a Barbie doll.

I hope you get what you want!

Nice work! I didn't actually have anything more specific in mind than the spelt-out answer. I was doing Christmas shopping and realised most of what I was buying could be described like that and thought it'd be funny if that was someone's actual wish. Maybe the wording could have been a little clearer.
